# Calculation not working after save file phpspreadseet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Strange...I only replace some value in a template xlsx with setCellValue(), I save the file and when I open it in Excel 2013 or Libre Office calc, the calculation are not done.. But it's ok in Excel 365...
I must use calculation without condition in Libre Office to get the good result...
Is there a way to tell phpspreadsheet to force calculation of the whole spreadsheet before saving it ?
Thank's

Guen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution this night... It is beacause I put some null and empty values in some cell and formula MIN() doesn't like this !
It's OK now !

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [calculation engine](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/calculation-engine/).